# Can I say "プロような英書き方"?

Tags: translation

I want to express "*professional English writing style". The writing styles I mean are the ones used in white papers, *The Economist*, etc. Can I say:

> プロような英書きかた{えがきかた}。

Using the precedent of
**"英語の文法" ---> "英文"**

Can I do this:
**"英語の書き方"** ---> **"英[書]{が}き方{かた}"**

Might it sound clever and learned if said by a non-native, but perhaps is not something that a native would actually say.

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds anything but clever. You need の after a noun when using ような; 英文 does not stand for grammar as you suggest (on the other hand it is a good candidate for the phrase you want to express);
 えがき is a verb on its own and 描き方 is widely used phrase. Anyway, an idea of how you want to use the phrase would definitely help.

Comment: @macraf Can you elaborate on your asserting "You need の after a noun when using ような; "?

Comment: @macraf The context is that there are many English writing styles. I want to express the writing style that has the highest level of professionalism. This style is used in white papers, articles published in `The Economist`, doctoral theses, etc. so, that is what I'm thinking about. Many native speakers would be unable to write at that level.

Comment: That much I understood. I was thinking whether you wanted to praise someone or make a title for a chapter in "how to write like a pro" blog post, or else?

Comment: Not praise at all. Just, a language can be divided into several skill sets. One skill set is the ability to write at a professional level. Writing at this level in your native language is super difficult. Writing at this level in a second language would be almost impossible. That's the best I can do to explain "professional level writing skills."

Comment: I can't quite elaborate on my assertion for the requirement of の. It's just what every grammar dictionary lists as proper form and how majority of Japanese use. Seems I am not the only one [claiming so](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/similar.html#part2) on the internet.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking **how** you want to use the phrase, but you keep explaining **what** you wanted to say. That leads nowhere.

Comment: I would also take caution using プロ. That sounds more like you are some kind of sports player and generally in situations where you want to express professionalism, shortening the word itself will not show you to be professional at all. You could use either the full work プロフェショナル or even ネイティブ. Something along the lines of プロフェショナルな英語文体 or ネイティブレベルの英語文体。「書き方」has a literal meaning of how to write, not necessarily writing style. Kanji has a 書き方, Japanese has a writing style. As in English, letters have a 書き方 and English has a writing style.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder yeah. Now, I can kind of feel that "プロ" has a lighter meaning that "professionalism"... I'm talking with some natives tonight; I'll try to thresh it out of them. thanks.

Comment: @ No problems. Good luck. Let us know how you went.

Answer (score 3):

The word for *writing style* in this context is 文体{ぶんたい}.

Here are some options to qualify that:

- かしこまった *rigid*, *strict*, or *official*
- 洗練された *polished*
- 高度な *advanced*
- 高尚な *refined, high culture* (perhaps a little snooty)
- 論文のような *like an academic paper*
- 公式文書のような *like an official document*
- 経済誌のような *like an economic journal*

Chain them together as you see fit, for example:

> 経済誌のようなかしこまった英語の文体